# HttpInterceptor catchError does not catch - Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to handle HTTP errors with interceptor but catchError method does not seems to fire when error occurs (422). None of errors are intercepted by this method.
Providers in app.module has added (i can read events and 200 respons).

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
HttpRequest,
HttpHandler,
HttpEvent,
HttpInterceptor,
HttpErrorResponse, HttpResponse,
} from '@angular/common/http';

import {Observable, throwError} from 'rxjs';
import {catchError} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class RequestInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

constructor() {}

intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler):         
Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

return next.handle(request)
  .pipe(
    catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      console.log(error);
      return throwError(error);
    }));
}
}
```

Comment: Did you add it to module providers list?

Comment: I see, you added to providers

Comment: can you try this
.pipe(tap((response: any) => {
                    console.log(response);
                    return response;
                }))

Comment: check whether you are able to catch response.

Comment: @RakeshMakluri yes I can catch response but not where error occurs

Comment: Same code like yours working fine in my local. Can you see any other console errors, when there is an http error?

Comment: @RakeshMakluri checked on Chrome and Firefox - still nothing.

Comment: Can you provide any reproducible stackblick/codesandbox?

Comment: Thats all. Beside I send req to server with proxyConfig

Comment: I copied exact code of yours and tested here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-http-interceptors-lguqcn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

It is working properly. May be issue is with other code.

Answer (score 0):

try like this once, i hope this is useful to you.

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpXsrfInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
   constructor(private tokenService: HttpXsrfTokenExtractor) { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): 
  Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const headerName = 'X-XSRF-TOKEN';
    const token = this.tokenService.getToken() as string;
    if (token && !req.headers.has(headerName)) {
      req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set(headerName, token) });
    }

    return next.handle(req)
        .do(sucess => {/*todo*/}
            , err => this.handleError(err));
 }

 private handleError(err: any) {
    TODO: Handle error.
 }
}
```